# Why won't OpenCL link with gcc after installing the fglrx driver and amd app sdk?

Tags: linux, gcc, links

I have installed the fglrx driver on my machine following this tutorial: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Fedora_18_Installation_Guide, installed the opencl-headers package, and finally installed the amd app sdk When I run

```
gcc -lOpenCL someprogram.c
```

I am given the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the following from fglrxinfo

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6310 Graphics
OpenGL version string: 4.2.12422 Compatibility Profile Context 13.152
```

And there is no libopencl.so in /usr/lib64/

I figured out how to link it by running

```
gcc -I/opt/AMDAPP/include -L/opt/AMDAPP/lib/x86_64 -lOpenCL hellocl.c -o hello
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the actual library for the `ld` to link. The headers are only required for the compilation, not the linking. It will be looking for a file called `libOpenCL.so` in your library path. From the `ld` manpage:

```
   -l namespec
   --library=namespec
       Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of
       files to link.  This option may be used any number of times.  If
       namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path
       for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path 
       for a file called libnamespec.a.

       On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for 
       files other than libnamespec.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
       systems, ld will search a directory for a library called 
       libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a.  
       (By convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.)  
       Note that this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always
       specifies a file called
       filename.
```

Try symlinking the library to the name the build system is looking for.

```
ln -s /usr/lib64/libopencl.so /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so
```